# Is definite integral a continuous transform on functional space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Consider the space of all Lipschitz continuous functions on $[0,1]$ equipped with the infinity norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ be Lipschitz.

Is $L(f)=\int_{0}^{1}f dx$ continous?

Comment: You mean the functional $L$ is continuous!

Answer (score 0):

$|L(f)|=|\int_0^1 f(x) dx |\leq \int_0^1 \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)| dx=\int_0^1 \|f\| dx =\|f\|.\; $ So $\|L\|\leq 1$ so $L$ is continuous.

Also we have $\|L\|=1$ because if $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ then $L(f)=\|f\|=1.$